# Manual Futures and aysnc move: Type doesn't live long enough even though I'm cloning it

Tags: rust, future, lifetime, rust-futures

I've got this function that is doing some work with manually created futures.

```rust
    pub type Response = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<T, Error>> + Send>>

    pub fn get_list<T: DeserializeOwned + Send + 'static, P: serde::Serialize + Clone + Send>(
        &self,
        path: &str,
        params: P,
    ) -> Response<List<T>> {
        use futures::future::FutureExt;

        let resp: Response<List<T>> = self.get_query(path, params.clone());

        let params = params.clone();
        let resp = resp.then(move |res| async move {
            let params = params; // Take ownership of params.
            match res {
                Ok(list) => list.params(&params),
                Err(e) => Err(e),
            }
        });

        return Box::pin(resp);
    }
```

I'm getting the error:

```
   the parameter type `P` may not live long enough
...so that the type `futures_util::future::Then<Pin<Box<dyn futures_util::Future<Output = Result<List<T>, error::Error>> + std::marker::Send>>, impl futures_util::Future, [closure@src/client/async.rs:142:30: 148:10]>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
```

I don't want to make `P` static, but I don't mind cloning my way to a solution.  My understanding is that using `async move` should move params and take ownership, so I don't need any sort of lifetime on P.   But obviously there's still something weird going on with lifetimes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you need `P: 'static`. Right now, you are cloning `params`, but that doesn't prevent the type `P` from *containing references* that would become invalid at some point, regardless of whether those *references* have been cloned. By adding the `P: 'static` bound, you prohibit `P` from containing such references.

`P: 'static` can be read as "values of type `P` may be kept around as long as their owner wants". It *does not* mean that `params` will be required to live indefinitely, only that it *could.*